# What declaration turns the below loop into infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops

Place your declaration for `i` at line 3 so that the loop becomes an infinite loop.

```
public class Puzzel3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Line 3
        while (i == i + 1) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like pop-quiz.

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding this question.

Comment: I think this question is better fitted for the [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), since its a puzzle.

Comment: Nah. It's just the guys homework. Thats why he asked it anonymously, so his teacher wont found out he copy/pasted an SO user's answer in his paper.

Comment: Any big floating point number will work as well I guess; doesn't have to be infinity. Since it's not possible to store such precision, it will just store the same value instead. ie: `1e100 + 1 == 1e100`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
double i=1/0.0;
```

It will turn the loop in infinite

Comment: it will throw exception devided by zero ? is not it ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller No it doesn't.

Comment: @AndroidKiller  no exception , i become Infinity.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ok , but why ? if you can explain then it will be helpful. Because this type of code generally throws this type of exception, right ? i also faced once. Devided by zero exception

Comment: @AndroidKiller `double` can express *infinity*, `int` cannot. You will get an exception if you do `int i = 1 / 0;`.

Comment: @AndroidKiller   That's because integers don't have values for +/-Inf, NaN, and don't allow division by 0, while floats do have those special values.

Answer (score 17):

Math says, that **Infinity** + 1 == **Infinity**, so

```
// The declaration required
double i = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

// It's infinite loop now...
while (i == i + 1) {
  System.out.println(i);
}

System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Also `-infinity + 1 == - infinity` :D

Answer (score 1):

The while loop is infinite if the loop condition remains true. Since the expression only depends on `i`, and `i` is not assigned in the loop body, that is equivalent to the loop condition being true on first evaluation.

Therefore, the question is for which values of which types the expression `i == i + 1` is true.

Java has the following types:

- reference types: do not support the `+` operator, except for strings, which get longer by concatentating "1", and therefore can not remain identical.
- primitive types:

  - boolean: does not support `+`
  - integral types: adding 1 is guaranteed to change the value, even in case of overflow
  - floating point types: a float of floating point type is either:

    - positive 0: 0- + 1 is 1 and therefore != 0
    - negative 0: 0+ + 1 is 1 and therefore != 0
    - NaN: NaN + 1 is NaN, but NaN != NaN
    - **positive infinity**: inf+ + 1 is inf+, and therefore == inf+
    - **negative infinity**: inf- + 1 is inf-, and therefore == inf-
    - normal: c + 1 is not an accurate computation. Roughly speaking, 1 is added to c, and the nearest float (or double) to that value is taken as the result. Whether that float (or double) is distinct from the initial value depends on the density of floating point values around c. Internally, a floating point type is represented by a sign bit, and two fixed-with integers m and e, where the value of the float is given by s * m * 2^e.

      - Adding 1 will unlikely change e (and if it does, the result is distinct anyway). Otherwise:

        - if e <= 0, adding 1 will change m
        - if e == 1, adding 1 **might** change m, **depending on the rounding mode**
        - if e > 1, adding 1 will not change m, and therefore c + 1 == c. Now, for which values will this occur?

          - For `float`, m < 2^24. Therefore, e > 1 if **c >= 2^25** or **c <= - (2^25)**
          - For `double`, m < 2^53. Therefore, e > 1 if **c >= 2^54** or **c <= -(2^54)**

Those ought to be all cases :-)